# Dart : Isolate not working when using html import

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I found this very strange and unfortunate behavior in Dart. When I import 'dart:html' in my main file, my Isolate stops working.

With my file "isolate.dart" :

```dart
main(){
  print('BAM');
}
```

This prints "BAM":

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() {
  Isolate.spawnUri(Uri.parse('isolate.dart'), [], null);
}
```

but this prints nothing :

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  Isolate.spawnUri(Uri.parse('isolate.dart'), [], null);
}
```

How can I get Isolate to work while using the html import?

UPDATE :
I've found this code https://github.com/TomCaserta/ExampleIsolate and tried to work it to find the problem. It seems like the print() call from the Isolate is causing problems.

Comment: I added the links as promised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are known bugs/limitations. It is being worked on.

Currently it is not possible to access functionality of the 'dart:html' package in an isolate and 'print()' crashes the isolate probably because there is no package with a 'print' functionality available where the command can be redirected to.

<del>The Dart issue tracker seems not to be available currently.

I try again later to add some references.</del>

Some open issues that I think are related:

- [Print statement inside isolate crashes isolate.](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16402)
- [Isolate.spawn not allowed in Dartium DOM isolate](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17649)
- [Support spawn of dom isolates in Dartium](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16965)
- [Unable to break on breakpoint in library loaded by spawnUri](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16774)
- [isolate in dartium not creating httprequest, works when compiled to javascript](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16565)