# Dart: Using JsObject and window API in an isolate

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop, dart-isolates

I am having some difficulties making use of isolates in Dart. The first problem is I wanted to use dart:js to use a javascript library in one of my isolates. I tried with the following code:

```
void runCode(SendPort sendPort)
{
    print("still ok...");
    JsObject object = new JsObject(context['jsCode']);
    print("still ok?");
}

void main()
{
    ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
    JsObject object = new JsObject(context['jsCode']);
    print("ok so far");
    Isolate.spawn(runCode, receivePort.sendPort);
}
```

The code runs as far as "still ok..." in the runCode function and breaks when I try to use JsObject.

The second problem was I wanted to use the fileSystem API in the isolate. So I tried the following:

```
void runCode(SendPort sendPort)
{
    window.requestFileSystem.then((FileSystem filesytem) => print('ok'));
}

void main()
{
    ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();
    Isolate.spawn(runCode, receivePort.sendPort);
}
```

This second example breaks when I reach the filesystem.

I have read: [Dart : Isolate not working when using html import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419979/dart-isolate-not-working-when-using-html-import) and from here it suggests that dart:html cannot be used in an isolate. Is this the reason why the filesystem API will not work? Is this the same case for dart:js? Or am I completely missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: AFAIK this will be fixed with DDC (Dart development compiler) when there is no dependency on Dartium for development anymore which makes such scenarios complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read somewhere that only the main thread has access to the DOM, which would cause any other JS action to fail if not in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks - checked this and that was exactly it.